# Is it possible to know which facebook user clicked on a link shared on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

is it possible to know which facebook user clicked on a link that a user of my app shared on facebook?

Let me rephrase for clarity:
I want to know which friends of my app user have clicked on his shared links.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Facebook does not share this information.

What you could do is have each link shared point to your webserver, prompt the clicker to authorize your app, then you can grab the user id.